# ObjectOutputStream.writeObject() freezing when trying to write object between classes

Tags: java

I am a beginner programmer so please excuse any technically incorrect statements/incorrect use of terminology.

I am trying to make a program that reduces CNF SAT in DIMACS format to 3SAT, and then from 3SAT to 3Graph Coloring, and then 3Graph coloring to SAT again. The idea is to make it circular so that the output from one reduction can be piped straight into the input of another, AKA if you reduce a CNF to 3SAT, the program should automatically reduce the 3SAT to Graph coloring after if the use specifies it to.

I have chosen to represent CNFs in a LinkedHashMap in a class called CNFHandler. The LinkedHashMap is  where File = the DIMACS cnf formatted file and the CNF object is the CNF (which contains an ArrayList of Clause objects) that corresponds to the CNF.

In my CNFHandler class, I have a reduce object, and it's in this object that I am trying to initiate my piping functionality:

```java
    package CNFHandler;

    import SAT_to_3SAT_Reducer.Reducer;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Optional;

    public class CNFHandler {
        private Map<File, CNF> allCNFs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        private CNFReader reader;
        private Reducer reducer = new Reducer();

        // PIPES
        private Optional<ObjectInputStream> inputPipe;
        private Optional<ObjectOutputStream> outputPipe;

        // Instantiate Pipes

        public void setInputPipe(ObjectInputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputPipe = Optional.of(inputStream);
            }

            public void setOutputPipe(ObjectOutputStream outputStream) {
                this.outputPipe = Optional.of(outputStream);
            }

    //...
    // Skipping lines for brevity
    //...

        public void reduce(String filePath) {
            File path = new File(filePath);
            addCNF(filePath);
            CNF result = reducer.reduce(allCNFs.get(path));
            if (!outputPipe.isPresent()) {
                System.out.println(result.toDIMACS());
            } else {
                try {
                    outputPipe.get().writeObject(result);
                    outputPipe.get().close();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to run "writeObject" (within the try block in the reduce() method) the program doesn't seem to go past that point. I've tried using breakpoints in IntelliJ to see what's going on, but the best I could figure out was as follows:

- A Native method called `waitForReferencePendingList()` seems to be stuck waiting for something, and that's why it won't go past the writeObject method
- IntelliJ tells me "Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51236', transport: 'socket'" but I'm not sure why because I'm not using Sockets anywhere in my program

Here is the code for my Main method where I instantiate the ObjectOutputStreams :

```java
    import CNFHandler.CNFHandler;
    import GraphHandler.GraphHandler;

    import java.io.*;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                String inFile = "short_cnf.cnf";

                PipedOutputStream _S_3S_OUT_PIPE_STREAM = new PipedOutputStream();
                PipedInputStream _S_3S_IN_PIPE_STREAM = new PipedInputStream();
                _S_3S_IN_PIPE_STREAM.connect(_S_3S_OUT_PIPE_STREAM);

                ObjectOutputStream _S_3S_OUT_OBJECT_STREAM = new ObjectOutputStream(_S_3S_OUT_PIPE_STREAM);
                ObjectInputStream _S_3S_IN_OBJEECT_STREAM = new ObjectInputStream(_S_3S_IN_PIPE_STREAM);

                CNFHandler handler = new CNFHandler();
                handler.setOutputPipe(_S_3S_OUT_OBJECT_STREAM);
                handler.reduce(inFile);

                PipedOutputStream _3S_G_OUT = new PipedOutputStream();
                PipedInputStream _3S_G_IN = new PipedInputStream();
                _3S_G_IN.connect(_3S_G_OUT);

                ObjectOutputStream _3S_G_OUT_STREAM = new ObjectOutputStream(_3S_G_OUT);
                ObjectInputStream _3S_G_IN_STREAM = new ObjectInputStream(_3S_G_IN);

                GraphHandler graphHandler = new GraphHandler();
                graphHandler.setInputPipe(_S_3S_IN_OBJEECT_STREAM);
                graphHandler.setOutputPipe(_3S_G_OUT_STREAM);
                graphHandler.reduce();



            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The other weird thing is that the `writeObject()` method seems to work if I use a different kind of object, for example, if I instantiate a String within the `writeObject()` method in the same place it's being called in `reduce()`, or if I instantiate a new CNF object in the same place, it WILL write the object. But I can't do it this way because I have to pass along the values of the object as well (the clauses, etc.) so I don't know what to do.

This is my CNF class, in brief:

```java
package CNFHandler;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

public class CNF implements Serializable {
    protected int numVars;
    protected int numClauses;
    protected String fileName;

    // store all variables with no duplicates
    protected Set<String> allLiterals = new HashSet<>();
    protected ArrayList<Clause> clauses = new ArrayList<>();

     /*
     for printing to DIMACS: keep track of the max # of
     literals that are needed to print a clause
     for example if all clauses in the CNF file contain
     2 literals, and only one contains 3 literals
     then the literalsize will be 3 to ensure things
     are printed with proper spacing
     */
     protected int literalSize = -20;

     /*
     keep track of the label referring to the highest #ed literal
     just in case they are not stored in order -- this way when we perform
    reductions we can just add literals to the end and be sure we are not
    duplicating any
    */
     protected int highestLiteral = -10;

    public CNF(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    protected void addClause(String[] inputs) {
        try {
            Clause clauseToAdd = new Clause();

            // add literals to the hashset, excluding dashes that indicate negative literals
            for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length - 1; i++) {
                // removing whitespace from the input
                String toAdd = inputs[i].replaceAll("\\s+", "");;

                // in case the variable is false (has a dash before the int), remove the dash to standardize storage
                String moddedToAdd = inputs[i].replaceAll("[-]*", "");


                 /*
                 if an unknown variable is in the stream, reject it.
                 (we're basically checking here if the variable set is full,
                 and if it is and the variable we're trying to add is new,
                 then it can't be added)
                 */
                    if ((!allLiterals.contains(moddedToAdd)) && (allLiterals.size() == numVars) && (moddedToAdd.trim().length() > 0)) {
                        throw new FailedCNFException();
                    }

                    // add the original input (so not the regex'd one but the one that would be false if it had been input as false
                    clauseToAdd.addLiteral(toAdd);

                    if (!allLiterals.contains(moddedToAdd) && !moddedToAdd.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        allLiterals.add(moddedToAdd);

                        /*
                        change the highestLiteral value if the literal being added is "bigger" than the others that have been seen
                         */
                        if(highestLiteral < Integer.parseInt(moddedToAdd)) {
                            highestLiteral = Integer.parseInt(moddedToAdd);
                        }
                    }
            }

            if (clauseToAdd.getNumberOfLiterals() > literalSize) {
                literalSize = clauseToAdd.getNumberOfLiterals();
            }

            clauses.add(clauseToAdd);

        } catch (FailedCNFException e) {
            System.out.println("The number of variables that have been introduced is too many!");
        }
    }

    public void makeClause(String[] inputs) {
        try {
            if (inputs[inputs.length - 1].equals("0")) {
                addClause(inputs);
            } else throw new FailedCNFException();
        } catch (FailedCNFException f) {
            System.out.println("There is no 0 at the end of this line: ");
            for (String s : inputs ) {
                System.out.print(s + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void initializeClauses (String[] inputs) {
        setNumVars(inputs[2]);
        setNumClauses(inputs[3]);
    }

    public String toDIMACS () {
        String toReturn = "p cnf " + getNumVars() + " " + getNumClauses() + "\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < clauses.size()-1; i++){
            Clause c = clauses.get(i);
            toReturn += c.toDIMACS(literalSize) + "\n";
        }
        toReturn += clauses.get(clauses.size()-1).toDIMACS(literalSize);

        return  toReturn;
    }

    /*
    Override tostring method to print clauses in human-readable format
     */
    @Override
    public String toString () {
        if(highestLiteral != -10) {
            String toReturn = "(";
            for (int i = 0; i < clauses.size() - 1; i++) {
                Clause c = clauses.get(i);
                toReturn += c + "&&";
            }
            toReturn += clauses.get(clauses.size() - 1).toString() + ")";

            return toReturn;
        } else {
            return "Add some clauses!";
        }
    }

       public String toString (boolean addFile) {
        String toReturn = "";

        if (addFile) {
            toReturn += "src/test/ExampleCNFs/" + fileName + ".cnf: \n";
        }

        toReturn +=  "(";
        for(int i = 0; i < clauses.size()-1; i++){
            Clause c = clauses.get(i);
            toReturn += c + "&&";
        }
        toReturn += clauses.get(clauses.size()-1).toString() + ")";

        return  toReturn;
    }

    //=============================================================================
    // HELPER FUNCTIONS
    //=============================================================================

    public void setNumVars(String vars) {
        numVars = Integer.parseInt(vars);
    }

    public void setNumClauses(String clauses) {
        numClauses = Integer.parseInt(clauses);
    }

    public Clause getClause(int index) {
        return clauses.get(index);
    }

    public void addLiteral(int newLiteral) {
        allLiterals.add(String.valueOf(newLiteral));
    }

    public void addLiterals(Set<String> newLiterals) {
        allLiterals.addAll(newLiterals);
    }

    public void addClauses(ArrayList<Clause> toAdd, int maxLiterals) {
        clauses.addAll(toAdd);
        numClauses += toAdd.size();
        // update literalsize if need be
        if (maxLiterals > literalSize) {
            literalSize = maxLiterals;
        }
    }

    //=============================================================================
    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    //=============================================================================


    public void setNumVars(int numVars) {
        this.numVars = numVars;
    }

    public void setNumClauses(int numClauses) {
        this.numClauses = numClauses;
    }

    public int getNumVars() {
        return numVars;
    }

    public int getNumClauses() {
        return numClauses;
    }

    public ArrayList<Clause> getClauses() {
        return clauses;
    }

    public Set<String> getAllLiterals() {
        return allLiterals;
    }

    //
    // LITERAL SIZE REPRESENTS THE MAXIMUM NUMBER OF LITERALS A CLAUSE CAN CONTAIN
    //
    public int getLiteralSize() {
        return literalSize;
    }

    public void setLiteralSize(int literalSize) {
        this.literalSize = literalSize;
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
        return "src/test/ExampleCNFs/" + fileName + ".cnf";
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    //
    // HIGHEST LITERAL REPRESENTS THE HIGHEST NUMBER USED TO REPRESENT A LITERAL
    // IN THE DIMACS CNF FORMAT
    //
    public int getHighestLiteral() {
        return highestLiteral;
    }

    public void setHighestLiteral(int highestLiteral) {
        this.highestLiteral = highestLiteral;
    }

    public void setHighestLiteral(String highestLiteral) {
        this.highestLiteral = Integer.parseInt(highestLiteral);
    }
}
```

Can someone give me some insight as to what's going on here, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have no idea what data your handling, nor what libraries you need for this to compile, so I can't help you with that. Perhaps if you were to mention that, more users could give it a go. You should probably also include the `setOutputPipe()` method. Other than that I noticed that you're closing your `outputstream` in `CNFHandler`. I don't think you should be doing that, since `CNFHandler` didn't open it.

Comment: These pipe streams are intended to be used by different threads: one or read and one to write. I don't see any threads here. Without an active reading thread your writes to the pipe cannot but block as soon as the internal buffer is full. Andi The only 4K IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, neither of the symptoms are actually relevant to your question:

> A Native method called `waitForReferencePendingList()` seems to be stuck waiting for something.

You appear to have found an internal thread that is dealing with the processing of `Reference` objects following a garbage collection.  It is *normal* for it to be waiting there.

> IntelliJ tells me "Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51236', transport: 'socket'"

That is Intellij saying that it has connected to the debug agent in the JVM that is running your application.  Again, this is normal.

<sup>If you are trying to find the cause of a problem via a debugger, you need to find the application thread that is stuck.  Then drill down to the point where it is actually stuck and look at the corresponding source code to figure out what it is doing.  In this case, you need to look at the standard Java SE library source code for your platform.  Randomly looking for clues rarely works ...</sup>

---

Now to your actual problem.

Without a stacktrace or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it is not possible to say with certainty what is happening.

However, I suspect that `writeObject` is simply stuck waiting for something to read from the "other end" of the pipeline.  It looks like you have set up a `PipedInputStream` / `PipedOutputStream` pair.  This has only a limited amount of buffering.  If the "writer" writes too much to the output stream, it will block until the "reader" has read some data from the input stream.

> The other weird thing is that the writeObject() method seems to work if I use a different kind of object ...

The other kind of object probably has a smaller serialization which fits into the available buffer space.